# C# DLL Injection

Tags: c#, dll-injection

Is it possible to inject a DLL file into a process such as explorer or svchost using C#? I know this is possible in C++ but is it in C#? If so would it matter how the DLL was written, e.g. would it differ betweeen a C++ DLL or a Visual Studio C# .NET DLL? If this is at all possible could someone post the code that I could use to do this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes it is possible: http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-to-inject-a-managed-assembly-dll

Since that link appears to be down, here's a cached version: http://web.archive.org/web/20101224064236/http://codingthewheel.com/archives/how-to-inject-a-managed-assembly-dll

Comment: I have now created and injected a C# DLL that shows a messagebox but when it is injected into explorer nothing happens. Is there something I have to do to get it started?

Comment: Ok, I will post it as a new question :)

Comment: next time copy necessary content from the site.. it's down and I am missing help because of this..

Comment: @ChrisDD And that's worth a downvote is it? And how can you be sure that copying the details would not have violated copyright?

Comment: Yes because it spent my time & it's not actually useful anyhow. Or what do you think the downvote is for?

Comment: @ChrisDD I think you have a problem with a spurious sense of entitlement. You really think that I have wasted your time?!

Comment: @ChrisDD I found a cached version. You could have done so yourself. See the updated version of the answer.

Comment: Dude, I would shake you hand if I could. That link is EXACTLY the type of explanation I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry to gravedig on this, but @DavidHeffernan, it's best to give the pertinent information in the answer, not just a link. Link only answers are subject to closure by SO rules, he's not wrong

Comment: @Christopher That is true, but does not justify the antagonistic comment from Erti. In this instance though, summarising the off site link would require a lot of effort on my part. I didn't do it. Forgive me for that please.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Understandable enough, and you were kind enough to come back with a cached link, but SO is meant to be as close to a closed system as possible. Search topics, find answers, without leaving the site. I feel like I've preaching to the choir a bit, though, since you're top .01% :) Thanks for the answer, anyway. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Christopher I know. And most times I would put more text in. This topic I know little about so I'd probably have written it wrongly anyway. And maybe I was just busy elsewhere! Anyway, thanks for the interest. I appreciate your comments.